# Clear bt-click method function when the page is updated

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my button:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ...//things it does
}
```

When I update the page, google chrome (for ex) asks me if I want to redo the action above. Lay people will press continue and the action is gonna happen, but it cant happen. How can I clear this action from "memory" for it don't happens again?

thanks a lot!

Comment: After you have finished processing in the button click do a Response.Redirect back to the same page

Comment: if e put redirect back the sessions i have will be cleared?

Comment: Nope, that will only happen if you do something like call Session.Abandon() or the app pool restarts

Comment: Do you mean that if the refresh the page with F5 it will fire the action again when you dont want it too?

Comment: I don't get why Chrome is asking such a thing. Have you some kind of custom headers?

Comment: @JoãoPauloOliveiraFernandes Glad it helped, will add as answer so you accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have done your processing in the button click event you can then do a Response.Redirect back to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

When you click `F5` browser resend to server last request. If the last request was a `POST` it will show a pop up asking user if he wants to resend the information. That's a standard behavior for every browser and you can't change it.

An existing pattern to avoid this problem is [`/Post/Redirect/Get`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)